# Manage Multiple Build Variants using Cordova ionic - Android Prject

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to create other build variants like staging, production apart from debug & release using cordova command as follow

```
cordova android build --stagging
```

On Native Android this can be achieved by
[Following this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Answer (score 1):

From cordova's [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-build-command), I don't see an option for it.

Comment: as per the documentation, yes there is no option, but there can't be any work around?

Comment: I guess you'll have to go the manual route. Create a distinct build for staging with debug or production mode and maintain it separately.